# webpages not displaying correctly

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, website

I am having a strange problem with my network.

Several computers on my network are having the issue but not all. The computers are both laptop and desktop, windows 7 and XP.

The problem is certain websites do not load in a web browser, the problem appears worse in internet explorer but it is now starting to affect chrome. The websites in question are pingable. I can see that it is not a problem with the website itself as the website works OK on some computers.

I have tried restarting my DNS server and rebooting my router this hasn't helped. I have tried different browsers. I have tried ipconfig /flushdns and release renew no improvement. Clearing the browsers cache to make sure its not a browser problem.

I am also pretty sure it is not a windows update as one laptop that is affected hasn't had updates installed for a while.

Any other suggestions of things I can try?

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a network can go slow:

- double routing (2 same IP's)
- DNS server is not getting the best info (try using opendns or google dns)
- proxyserver isn't performant
- physical cable has gone bad (try searching for CRC errors)
- Router is buggy (try reboot or upgrade firmware)
- using IPv4 and 6 at the same time (sometimes gives problems)
- ...